# Widely accepted methods for documenting PHP source code in an auto-doc way?

Tags: php, documentation, documentation-generation, code-documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic PHP Documentation Generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189516/automatic-php-documentation-generation)

I'm new to PHP, and my current job requires me to pick up the language at an extremely quick pace.

I'm a documentation stickler. I even like to write documentation. I'm familiar with accepted documentation syntax and tools for a handful of languages.

This is not the case for PHP.

I know there are always multiple methods for writing doc-able source code comments, and there are usually various tools for each language. However, I'm in an environment that hasn't mandated a standard way of commenting, nor a standard PHP autodoc tool. That gives me freedom to choose, and a bit of paralysis-by-analysis to go along with it.

Is phpDocumentor (http://www.phpdoc.org/) an acceptable standard tool for PHP autodocs?

Is it acceptable to follow the general JavaDoc guidelines for code when documenting PHP code?