# Is it possible to define a variable type in aptana like Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, aptana

I recently changed to Apatana to give it a try but there a some funcionality from Netbeans that I'd love to have in aptana.

- Is it possible to have variables type defined in comments. Example: /*@var $foo FooType*/. This way works in netbeans for php.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do some search actions on php documentation generation etc. It could lead you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189516/508702) for example.